# regex to replace link

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i've got the good old replace plain url to link question.
I'm using the linkify from Jeff Roberson's code,
but since it doesn't support pseudo urls (www.), I'm trying to add that in with another regex i found.
So far I'm stuck with this

```
  var replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  text.replace(pseudoUrlPattern, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>')
```

The text can be an html tag, and when the link has a closing p tag without any space it seems to include that in the link! I've tried forward look up but it seems I haven't got it right. 
An example text would be

```
 <p>www.something.here/something</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var text = "<p>www.something.here/something</p>";
var replacePattern2 = /(.*?)(((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+))((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/gim;
text.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="$4">$4</a>')
```

Based on this regex: http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's almost there, but www.something.com becomes a link to domain/www.something.com instead of http:// If there is no protocol i want it to add http, otherwise I want it to use the one in the text. Plus it changes emails in the form of some.thing@else.com to domain/thing@else.com

Comment: I think it will work if we remove the support for email. I have email regex after that.. var emailAddressPattern = /(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z_]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))+/gim; After I run that replacePattern2 I will run the emailAddressPattern.. so if we can somehow either combine those two, or exclude email patterns I think it will work